# Smoothing the values of the column with the mean or median of the members belong to the same bin

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Dataframe `df` is given using `df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[10, 15, 12, 19, 11, 20, 25]})` as:

```
     A
0   10
1   15
2   12
3   19
4   11
5   20
6   25
```

The result of equal-frequency binning of the column `A` by using `df['B'] = pd.cut(df['A'], bins = 2)`
is the following:

```
    A    B
0   10  (9.985, 17.5]
1   15  (9.985, 17.5]
2   12  (9.985, 17.5]
3   19  (17.5, 25.0]
4   11  (9.985, 17.5]
5   20  (17.5, 25.0]
6   25  (17.5, 25.0]
```

How can we simply have the mean (or median) of the elements of the column `A` which belong to the same bin instead of the intervals in column `B`? That is, how to have the column `B` as the following:

```
    A    B
0   10  12
1   15  12
2   12  12
3   19  21.33
4   11  12
5   20  21.33
6   25  21.33
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could group by the bins and [transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) to the mean or median, depending on what you want:

```
>>> df.groupby(pd.cut(df['A'], bins=2)).transform('mean')
           A
0  12.000000
1  12.000000
2  12.000000
3  21.333333
4  12.000000
5  21.333333
6  21.333333
>>> df.groupby(pd.cut(df['A'], bins=2)).transform('median')
      A
0  11.5
1  11.5
2  11.5
3  20.0
4  11.5
5  20.0
6  20.0
```

For the interval midpoint check @sacuL’s (now deleted?) answer. It was `pd.cut(df['A'], bins=2).map(lambda itv: itv.mid)`, or the slightly faster:

```
>>> df['B'] = pd.IntervalIndex(pd.cut(df['A'], bins=2)).mid
>>> df
    A        B
0  10  13.7425
1  15  13.7425
2  12  13.7425
3  19  21.2500
4  11  13.7425
5  20  21.2500
6  25  21.2500
```

Comment: ```df['B'] = df.groupby('B')['A'].transform('mean')``` is what I've been looking for.